# I want my controller to wait for my directive to be completed before doing other things

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, synchronous

I have this controller function :

```
$scope.keypadEnter = function () {
    userService.isCodeValid($scope.code).then(function (result)
    {
        if (JSON.parse(result.data)) {
            $scope.highlight("lime").then(function () {;
                console.log("redirecting ...");
                $location.path('/clockin');
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.highlight("red");
        }

        $scope.code = "";
    });
};
```

The controller calls a *service* (userService) function (isCodeValid) that returns true if the specified code is valid, otherwise false.

Look closely at these two lines :

```
$scope.highlight("lime");
$location.path('/clockin');
```

$scope.highlight is a *directive* function that triggers a jquery (highlight) animation :

```
angular.module('clockin').directive('grDisplay', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.highlight = function (color) {
                $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

I would like these two lines to be executed **synchronously**, to be able to see the highlight animation (`$scope.highlight(...)`) **before** being redirected (`$location.path(...)`).

How can I do that ?

**Update :**

I've changed my directive code to the following (I have exagerated the timeout to 5 seconds):

```
angular.module('clockin').directive('grDisplay', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.highlight = function (color) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $element.effect("highlight", { color: color }, 500)
                $timeout(deferred.resolve(), 5000);

                return deferred.promise;

            }
        }
    };
});
```

And my controller function to the following :

```
$scope.keypadEnter = function () {
    userService.isCodeValid($scope.code).then(function (result)
    {
        if (JSON.parse(result.data)) {
            $scope.highlight("lime").then(function () {;
                console.log("redirecting ...");
                $location.path('/clockin');
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.highlight("red");
        }

        $scope.code = "";
    });
};
```

When running, I still have the same results : I can see the highlight but it doesn't have time to finish as I am redirected.

And I have this error :

```
TypeError: Objet expected    at Anonymous function
```

(hxxp://localhost:18000/Scripts/angular.js:14261:11)    at completeOutstandingRequest 
(hxxp://localhost:18000/Scripts/angular.js:4387:7)    at Anonymous function 
(hxxp://localhost:18000/Scripts/angular.js:4688:7)

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could simply $watch the value returned by userService.isCodeValid($scope.code) ?

Comment: How about a scope.$broadcast from your directive?

Comment: Made an edit to my answer.  Instead of $timeout(deferred.resolve()... change that to $timeout(deferred.resolve, 5000)

Comment: Aha ! I thought resolve was a method, but it's an object. I removed the parentheses and back in the controller, the _then_ method effectively waits for the timeout to be over. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time on this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a deferred inside the `$scope.highlight` function call.  That function could return a deferred and when resolved, you change the `$location.path`.

If this happens too fast to physically see the highlight, you could also add a `$timeout` on the resolve of the deferred:

```
function MyDirective($q, $timeout) {
    controller : function ($scope, $element) {

       $scope.highlight = function () {
           var deferred = $q.defer();

           // do your highlight stuff

          // Resolve the deferred a second later
           $timeout(deferred.resolve, 1000);

           return deferred.promise;
       }
    }
);
```

Then you would invoke the function like this:

```
$scope.highlight("lime").then(function () {
   $location.path('/clockin');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @sma. I added my directive's code in my question. How can I integrate $q in my link object ?

Comment: Inject it into your main directive into the constructor function:

function MyDirective ($q, $timeout)

Comment: Edited my answer to hopefully illustrate this better.

Comment: I have edited my question to show you what I've tried, based on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply $watch the value returned by userService.isCodeValid($scope.code) ?

Something like :

```
$scope.val = userService.isCodeValid($scope.code);
$scope.$watch('val', function() {
     if($scope.val === true){
        $scope.highlight("lime");
        $location.path('/clockin');
     }
     else {
        $scope.highlight("red");
     }
});
```

*Note that I'm not a JS expert and lot of people could say this is dirty code :)*

Comment: Thanks for your input @euguerranws but my problem isn't the logic from the isCodeValid function. Even if I watch the value, $scope.highlight and $location.path will be ran asynchronously. That's what I need to avoid.